# smallest Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Definition: A graph G is bipartite if its vertices can be partitioned into two sets V1 and V2 and every edge joins a vertex in V1 with a vertex in V2. Bipartite graphs can be characterized by all circuits in such graphs having even length (if there are no circuits, the graph is also bipartite), where the length of a circuit or path is the number of edges in it 
What is the smallest bipartite graph?:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on your definition, but if you define bipartite as two-colorable or having no odd cycles, then the empty graph or the trivial graph are the minimal bipartite graphs.

Comment: A graph G is bipartite if its vertices can be partitioned into two sets V1 and V2 and every edge joins a vertex in V1 with a vertex in V2. Bipartite graphs can be characterized by all circuits in such graphs having even length (if there are no circuits, the graph is also bipartite), where the length of a circuit or path is the number of edges in it

Comment: with this definition it the answer still the same?

Comment: Well, if they're allowed to be empty, just take $V_1=V_2=\emptyset$ and the empty graph is bipartite.

Answer (score 1):

If by "smallest" you mean "number of vertices", then that is one possible answer.

But you could also remove the edge to leave two vertices and no edges, and perhaps you will consider this to be "smaller" than your example.

Comment: with the definition I edited into the first post, is the answer still the same?

Comment: According to the definition you have given, YoTengounLCD's answer is correct.  The definition I have mostly seen is that the "parts" of a bipartite graph must be non-empty sets of vertices.